# Dynamic select label overlap issue - IE7

Tags: jquery, select, internet-explorer-7

I have 9 select elements in a row and I'm using jQuery to dynamically change some of the options of a select depending on the option selected on the first select element. The problem is in IE7 when the options of a select are changed such that the width expands, the label of the subsequent select doesn't move along, the label remains overlapped on the select that has just budged forward. In FireFox when the select elements change the subsequent labels and select elements moving along fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a fixed width via CSS on the select elements that change, this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble modifying selects in IE7. Try removing the select from the DOM, making your changes and then placing the select back into the DOM. This usually solves my IE7 select issues.